# Amcharts - Gap between Y-axis title & axis

Tags: amcharts

I've tried setting the `autoMargins: true` and `autoMarginOffset: 50` expecting to see some space between the Y-Axis title & the Y-Axis. However, the whole chart moves towards the right as I increase the `autoMarginOffset`. I've also tried the `marginLeft` property.

The width of the plot `div` is 100%. I tried reducing this to about 80% to see if the above properties take effect. However, I'm not seeing what I expect to with these properties in place.

Could I get some guidance on which property to use please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to set specific gap between axis title and axis itself, I'm afraid.

The only (and unfortunately ugly) workaround is to put a line break `\n` and a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) into the axis title.

```
"valueAxes": [{
  // other axis properties
  // ...
  "title": "Axis title\n "
}]
```

On Windows you can type in a non-breaking space using Alt-0160. On Mac: Opt-Space.

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you Martyn. Appreciate your help.